# Thread won't release lock after wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized

Sorry if there are other similar questions but I couldn't find any, I am a beginner to concurrent programming and this problem has been bugging me for awhile, which I really need to understand what is the mistake I have made, or else I couldn't proceed into my assignment.

What I am trying to achieve is to print "1" from 'Test' that is handled by a thread and print "from Test 2" from 'Test 2' which is also handled by a thread, but only "1" is printed. What should I do?

```
================================

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test implements Runnable {

    Third third;

    public Test(Third third){
        this.third = third;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (third) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("1");
                    third.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }

            }
        }
    }
}

=====================


public class Test2 implements Runnable{
    Test test;
    Third third;

    public Test2(Test test, Third third){
        this.test = test;
        this.third = third;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            synchronized(third){
                third.notifyAll();
                System.out.println("from test 2");
            }
        }
    }
}

================================

public class Third {

}

==============================

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        Third third = new Third();
        Test test = new Test(third);
        Test2 test2 = new Test2(test, third);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(test);
        Thread t2= new Thread(test2);

        t1.run();
        t2.run();
        t2.join();
        t1.join();
    }
}
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTVcz.png)

Comment: Ad @Gaurav correctly points out, you should call start(). What is happening in your code: you have a single thread, which is executing main(), and is stuck waiting on the monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call run method directly as it will not create any thread.It invokes like a normal method. Instead of run() method, you should call start() method.

One more thing, what you're doing with shared resource Third. There could be synchronize method which is accessible by different thread.

Class name should be start with Capital letter and should follow CamelCase.

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

```
    Third third = new Third();
    Test test = new Test(third);
    Test2 test2 = new Test2(test, third);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(test);
    Thread t2= new Thread(test2);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t2.join();
    t1.join();
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for answering, i've been stuck here for tens of hours didn't know what's wrong with the code and even tried out many different approaches, without doubting the lines i have in my main class.. i feel so bad XD but thank you!